# Acumatica Error: Failed to Commit Splits Row

Tags: web-services, exception, erp, soapexception, acumatica

Can you please help us understand the root cause of the below error while trying to create Shipment using the Acumatica web services?

> Error    : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXException: Error #241: Failed to commit splits row.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically suggesting that while adding data to view called "splits" failed.  There split tables that store Bin/Lot/Serial data.  The reason could be many things but mostly key values were not set correctly while adding the records in these tables.

hope this helps!